# tlp icon removal

Tags: 19.10, tlp

I installed tlp on my laptop running ubuntu 19.10 hoping to lengthen my battery life. The installation created an icon on the top bar that looks like an erlenmeyer flask and it does nothing. Don't need it. Don't want it. How can I remove it? Thank you.

Comment: It seems it is the app indicator...is your question removing this icon while app indicator gnome-shell extension is always on?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I just want to hide or remove the icon without uninstalling tlp.

Comment: Hi.. Try to turn off gnome-shell extension `ubuntu-appindicatior`

Comment: ubuntu-appindicatior: command not found

Comment: Also, I found that gnome-tweaks has a "tlp switcher" extension which I can turn off. This removes the icon. I had uninstalled gnome-tweaks because of the flickering problem which made it difficult to use. I mentioned the flickering problem in a previous post but it has not yet been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The gnome-tweaks app has an option (tlp switcher) under the extensions category that will hide this icon. The gnome-tweaks app still suffers from flickering which makes it very difficult to use.